# Replace dictionary value in a separate file

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary, python-2.7

I'm on python 2.7.3. I wrote a simple code that searches through dictionary keys, and when it finds the key defined by `var_par`, it iteratively substitutes new values for it from a list `array`:

```
var_par = 'B'
array = [1.4, 2.6, 4.8, 3.56]

params = {
    "A":    ["A part of",      "#comment 1"],
    "B":    [1.2,              "#comment 2"],
    "C":    ["the test run.",  "#comment 3"]
}

for I in array:
    if var_par in params: params[var_par][0] = I
    execfile('script.py')
```

Now basically what I want to do and what my question is about is the following: I want to put my `params` dictionary in a separate file `parameters.dat`, and then do the same thing, but *physically* alter the value (in this case for `B`) for the given key defined by `var_par` and save the file before the script `script.py` is executed. The reason is that this script reads its input parameters from file.

I tried adding and playing around with

```
value_old = str(params[var_par][0])
value_new = str(I)

for key in fileinput.input("parameters.dat", inplace = 1): 
    print key.replace(value_old, value_new),
```

However, the problem I have with this addition is that whenever for instance both `C` and `B` share the same value, both are altered to the new value. (This is of course logic seeing that the code searches for the value, and not for the given key `var_par`.) Otherwise it works, but it is vital for the code of course not to have this flaw, which I am as of yet unable to resolve. On the other hand I have the feeling that it must not be that difficult and that I am close.

Thanks a lot for any input.

ps. I am a python beginner, so I am not very good at it, but will try to provide any assistance if/when needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `if var_par in params: params[var_par][0] = I` instead? That's much faster than looping through all the keys of `params`.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thank you for your comment. I also realized this and thought it could be written more efficient, but didn't address it yet. Edited my answer though.

Comment: If both the lists for `B` and `C` change if you alter one of them, then they are referring to the *same list*. You'll need to show us how you *really* build `params`.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for your input. Please see my own answer, I already solved my problem. (Maybe this will in the end also clarify where I wanted to go with my question.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to those who took the time to consider my question. However, I managed to solve the problem already myself. I hope the following bit of code might contribute also to other people's programming.

```
execfile('parameters.dat')

var_par = 'B'
array = [1.4, 2.6, 4.8, 5.6]

for I in array: # Start choosing the values in array

    if var_par in params: params[var_par][0] = I

    f = open('params_temp.dat', 'w')
    print >> f, 'params = {'
    for p in params:
        if type(params[p][0]) == str:
            print >> f, ''.join(map(str,['"', p,'"',':'])), '\t',
            print >> f, ''.join(map(str,['[', '"', params[p][0], '"', ','])), '\t', ''.join(map(str,['"', params[p][1], '"', ']', ',']))
        else:
            print >> f, ''.join(map(str,['"', p,'"',':'])), '\t',
            print >> f, ''.join(map(str,['[', params[p][0], ','])), '\t', ''.join(map(str,['"', params[p][1], '"', ']', ',']))
    print >> f, '}'
    f.close()
    os.remove('parameters.dat')
    os.rename('params_temp.dat', 'parameters.dat')

    execfile('script.py')
```

where `parameters.dat` solely contains (some *initial*) dictionary:

```
params = {
    "A":    ["A part of",      "#comment 1"],
    "B":    [1.2,              "#comment 2"],
    "C":    ["the test run.",  "#comment 3"]
}
```

The script will then iteratively produce the file `parameters.dat` after which `script.py` is called which will read the file, after which' termination the next value from `array` will be chosen, a new parameter file is produced, until `array` is depleted.

Note that to build the new dictionary correctly I do some sorting between strings and the rest. Also, I had to write the print statements such that no extra spaces are printed. I.e., `"B"` instead of `" B "` which will not be recognised as a dictionary key.

I am aware that this might be considered "the basics", but when you start learning something nothing really is basic.. ;) Also, if anybody knows how to program this in a less verbose way or improve it in any other way, I would be happy to hear.

Cheers,
Willem.